# Is there equivalent function of collidepoint for color?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a 2D game in order to learn python and pygame. The goal will be to control a red point and to get out of a dungeon. I'm making a map generator composed of rectangles and rectangles won't be the same color as the surface.

Is it possible to make my red point move only on the surface color (black) for exemple ?
With some collidepoint function or equivalent ?

I did a little code for exemple:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

X = 750
Y = 750

BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

done = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((X,Y))

X_circle = 375
Y_circle = 375


def mainloop():
    global BLACK, WHITE, RED, X, Y, done, screen, X_circle, Y_circle, Xmove, Ymove

    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,20)

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            Xmove = 0
            Ymove = 0

            screen.fill(BLACK)
            circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (X_circle,Y_circle), 15)
            Rect_WHITE = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (300, 200, 44, 46))
            pygame.display.update()


            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_KP4:
                    Xmove = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_KP6:
                    Xmove = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_KP8:
                    Ymove = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_KP5:
                    Ymove = 5

            if (X_circle+Xmove<750 and X_circle+Xmove>0):
                X_circle+=Xmove
            if (Y_circle+Ymove<750 and Y_circle+Ymove>0):
                Y_circle+=Ymove

            pygame.display.update()

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

mainloop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should move some stuff outside the event `for` loop. You definitely not need to draw the circle each event, this will slow down your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not equivalent `collidepoint` function for color.

`pygame.draw` functions can be used to draw geometrical forms, but are not intended to control game elements. `pygame` has other tools to do that (check the [pygame.sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) module for example).

You should implement yourself a function to compare if colors are overlapping, but if you go that way, you'll soon realize that you are reinventing the wheel.
Think of a `pygame.Surface` as a pixel map. Geometrical shapes on the surface are simply pixels colored with a color different from the background color.
In other words, each pixel has **one** color. When that color is changed (for example after the use of a `pygame.draw` function to draw a new shape) the previous color is lost.

In the end, you will need to create a way to remember the previous color at that given position, otherwise you can't compare anything. Well, `pygame` has already a way to track position, it's [pygame.Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). Which already has methods like `colliderect` and `collidepoint`.

Short story, use `pygame.Rect` or `pygame.Sprite` instances to keep track of your white rectangles, and check for collision of your point with them.

Comment: Indeed, after few research, i decided to go with the pygame.surface thing. I found this vid explaining exactly what i was searching for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JW_H7o-MmtI. So i will use surface.get_at((X,Y))==(color). I already tried this on the code i made for exemple and it's working. Thank you for pointing this out, Valentino.